# How is Administration stored in django?

Tags: python, django

When I do

```
`from django.apps import apps
 print(apps.get_app_config('admin').verbose_name)'
```

I get the result as 
    `Administration`

How is this result obtained? I cannot find anywhere written as administration, when instead of admin I put an installed app's name it shows the same name with capitalization. How is admin configured in django such that this results?

Answer (score 1):

It's defined exactly where you get it from, in the AppConfig. Here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/apps.py#L11